# How do I group parameters in a blazor component?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a button that optionally appears on a component, it needs a title and an OnClick event handler. I want to provide both in a single object so if it is null then I know not to show the button.

```
@if(null != CancelButton) {
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" @onclick="@Cancel">
        @CancelButton?.Text
    </button>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public ButtonInit? CancelButton { get; set; } = null;

    public struct ButtonInit {
        public ButtonInit(string text, EventCallback onClick) {
            Text = text;
            OnClick = onClick;
        }

        public string Text { get; }
        public EventCallback OnClick { get; }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Text}-button";
    }

    private Task Cancel()
    {
        return CancelButton?.OnClick.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

I cannot create an instance of ButtonInit class to provide it as a parameter.

```
private ButtonInit OkBtn = new ButtonInit("Create", OnConfirm);
```

Is there a regular way to achieve things like this or do I have to use two separate parameters?

Answer (score 1):

ButtonInit  is a nested type.

This should work:

```
private MyComponent.ButtonInit OkBtn = new MyComponent.ButtonInit("Create", OnConfirm);
```

but it is better to put ButtonInit in its own file.